# android ndk crash when using stl map 's operator []

Tags: android, c++, dictionary, stl, android-ndk

I have a map: `map < int64_t, Item* > m_items`;

When using `m_items[one_id]`, my app crashed.
But if I use `map<int64_t, Item*>::iterator iter = m_items.find(one_id)`, it's ok.

If I need to add an item I must use: `m_items.insert(make_pair(one_id, one_item));`

Why is this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an Android-specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what version of gcc you're using?
If it's gcc 4.5 or earlier this bug in gcc has caused Boost's unordered map's [] operator not to function correctly: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40145
Maybe you're seeing something similar.

If it's gcc 4.6 I'm not sure, but the C++11 at() method will be available to you, it's a little slower, but it is faster than find. [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at)